# What is the HTML concept called that links 2 select boxes together?

Tags: html

This is an odd question, and I think it belongs on Stack Overflow since it has to do with HTML/Javascript - if it doesn't belong, let me know and I'll ask it elsewhere.

I am trying to implement a component in my web application, but I do not know what it is called, so I don't know how to search for help on it!

It is where you have a list of things in a combo box on the left side, some arrows in the middle to send list items between combo boxes, and a combo box on the right side that shows the items you have selected.

Here is a "picture" of what I mean:

```
+-------+        +-------+
| item1 |  --->  | item2 |
| item3 |        |       |
| item4 |  <---  |       |
+-------+        +-------+
```

I'm sure there is a JQuery plugin for this too, so if anyone has any recommendations, I'd appreciate it.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no 'component' that will do this. This thread should help:

[Moving items in Dual Listboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204140/how-to-add-move-one-list-box-items-to-another-listbox-items-in-javascript)

You have both a jQuery and native javascript example.

Comment: Thanks - I knew there wasn't an HTML tag for it or anything - I probably mis-used the word "component" - but I appreciate the link - that's exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 2):

There isn't an HTML tag for this, it has to be implemented in JavaScript. It wouldn't be all that hard even without jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

There is also a jQuery plugin [here](http://www.meadmiracle.com/dlb/DLBDocumentation.aspx). The examples aren't very flashy, but they do the job.

Comment: Thanks for the example jQuery plugin!  +1